Modbus Tcp/ip Logosoft comfort V8
I'm doing a school project, that includes tcp/ip comunication between the logo and my computer, but I can't make it work. I am not trying to make a server, I just want to send a value from my computer to a net digital input of the logo.
Logo ip: 192.168.0.2
net input id: 1
tcp/ip port: 502
net input addres: 1
import socket
from umodbus import conf
from umodbus.client import tcp
 
conf.SIGNED_VALUES = True

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.0.2', 502))
 
message = tcp.write_single_coil(slave_id=1, address=1, value=1)

response = tcp.send_message(message, sock)
print(response)
sock.close()
print("Transfer finished")

try:
    from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # Si la primera opción falla, usa la segunda opción de importación
    from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

ip_address = '192.168.0.2'
port = 502  # Puerto por defecto para Modbus TCP

client = ModbusTcpClient(ip_address, port)

if not client.connect():
    print("No se pudo conectar al cliente Modbus")
else:
    print("Conexión exitosa")

    # Escribir un valor digital en una bobina
    def write_digital(client, address, value):
        result = client.write_coil(address, value)
        if result.isError():
            print(f"Error al escribir el valor en la puerta digital: {result}")
        else:
            print("Valor escrito correctamente en la puerta digital")

    # Dirección de la bobina digital (depende de la configuración del Siemens LOGO!)
    coil_address = 0x0001
    # Valor a escribir en la bobina digital (True para encender, False para apagar)
    digital_value_to_write = True

    # Escribir el valor digital
    write_digital(client, coil_address, digital_value_to_write)

    # Cerrar la conexión
    client.close()
    print("Conexión cerrada")

Probe dos codigos, pero ninguno funcionó, el primero devolvio este error:I tried this two codes, but none of them worked, the first one returns this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\modbus.py", line 16, in <module>
    response = tcp.send_message(message, sock)
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\umodbus\client\tcp.py", line 261, in send_message
    response_error_adu = recv_exactly(sock.recv, exception_adu_size)
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\umodbus\utils.py", line 132, in recv_exactly
    chunk = recv_fn(size - recv_bytes)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
>>> 

I tried this two codes, but none of them worked, the first one returns this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\modbus.py", line 16, in <module>
    response = tcp.send_message(message, sock)
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\umodbus\client\tcp.py", line 261, in send_message
    response_error_adu = recv_exactly(sock.recv, exception_adu_size)
  File "C:\Users\ruths\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\umodbus\utils.py", line 132, in recv_exactly
    chunk = recv_fn(size - recv_bytes)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
>>> 

the second one returns:[WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
and I don't know what to do.

Please check that you can query the device using a known good tool (such as mbpoll/Modpoll) - this helps establish that the remote device is working as expected and there are not other issues. You may find the answer to this question useful (looks identical to your issue, note that including screenshots showing the LOGO! settings, similar to those in the answer there, would assist us in answering your question).

THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS YOU, GOD BLESS YOU
